# Apache Spark multiple joins on data frames

Tags: apache-spark

I'm working on a data processing application using Spark that needs to transform and combine many sources (10-20) together resulting in one file. All sources have a common key to join on. Is the best approach here to join one by one by materializing each operation to parquet files? or join multiple DFs at once? I've run into performance issues with the latter but would like to know what the best practices are.

UPDATE:
After switching to Spark 2.0 I noticed joins on many tables are now more reliable and more performant.